# What viewers can play GIF animated images?

Tags: gif

On Manjaro running [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/), I don't seem to have an image viewer that can play animated GIF files.

I think that [Gwenview](https://userbase.kde.org/Gwenview) can and I have it on my KDE system. But on a Fluxbox system I would like to avoid too many KDE dependencies.

Comment: You can use `animate` provided by ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gwenview, as I said, but that's not what I wanted.

gThumb can do it. It comes with few dependencies but looks alien in Fluxbox.

A less desktop-dependent solution is [#2 under here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=18886):

Install `gifsicle.`

Create a desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GIFview 
Exec=gifview -a %f
Icon=gif
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=true
MimeType=image/gif
```

and put it into ~/.local/share/applications.

Answer (score 9):

You can you use nearly any [web browser](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications/Internet#Web_browsers), as they should play GIFs just fine.

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to avoid dependencies, you might also consider [sxiv](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv). It can play animated gifs using the `-a` flag, and only depends on imlib2.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC/videolan](http://www.videolan.org/) should do fine and is available on most systems.